# How to set background-image above background-color

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

I want to set `background-image` above the `background-color` (the `background-image` is a line). [See codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OGKoMz) and snippet:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.class1 {
  background: transparent url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/strike.png) repeat-x;
}

.class2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5rem !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td class="class1">
      <span class="class2">S</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that instead of setting background on two classes you can set it in `.class2` itself by using `background: url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/strike.png) repeat-x, red` (the image mentioned first will be stacked over the red background mentioned last) - see demo below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.class1 {
  padding: 10px; /* for illustration */
}

.class2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/strike.png) repeat-x,
              red; /* changed*/
  border-radius: 5rem !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td class="class1">
      <span class="class2">S</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

#### Solution

If you want to have the background image to extend over the full `td`, one option is to use `radial-gradient` for the red circle and combining it with background-image for the line. Note that here the *text is above the red background color and the line*:

```css
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td{
border: 1px solid black;
}

td.class1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/strike.png) repeat-x,
              radial-gradient(farthest-side,red 70%, transparent 72%);
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td class="class1">
      <span class="class2">S</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you want a *strikethrough effect* , you could place the line `background-image` over the `<span>` background and text, by use *negative `z-index`* on the `<span>` - see demo below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.class1 {
  padding: 10px; /* for illustration */
  background: transparent url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/strike.png) repeat-x;
  background-position: center;
}

.class2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5rem !important;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; /* added */
  z-index: -1; /* added */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td class="class1">
      <span class="class2">S</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Yet another option for the *strikethrough effect* is using a *pseudo element* so that you don't have to mess with `z-index` - see demo below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.class1 { /* added */
  padding: 10px; /* for illustration */
  position: relative;
}

td.class1:after { /* added */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/strike.png) repeat-x;
  background-position: center; /* added */
}

.class2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5rem !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td class="class1">
      <span class="class2">S</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry Seem my Question is not clear. I want the background image (The line)  display width 100% of td tag like what i do last time and above the backgroud color also letter

Comment: big thanks! using the pseudo element work for my code

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have a different class named `table.class1`
rather this will work well

```
.class2 {
   text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 5rem !important;
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/strike.png) repeat-x;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Seem my Question is not clear. I want the background image (The line)  display width 100% of td tag like what i do last time and above the backgroud color also letter